# nested for loop is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, nested-loops

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/tradebill/pages/main/employee/attendance.css">
<style>
    select {
        width: 10%;
    }

    #experiment_month {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 10% 10% 10% 10% 10% 10% 10%;
        grid-gap: 1rem;
        background-color: transparent;
        padding-top: 3rem;
    }

    #experiment_month div {
        background-color: red;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: .4rem;
        color: white;
        font-size: 3rem;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 10% 10% 10% 10% 10% 10% 10%;
        grid-template-rows: 10% 10% 10% 10% 10%;
        grid-gap: 1rem;
    }
</style>

<select name="" id="year" class="year">
    <option value="">select</option>

    <option value="2021">2021</option>
    <option value="2021">20222</option>
</select>
<select name="" id="month">
    <option value="">select</option>

    <option value="january">january</option>
    <option value="february">february</option>
</select>
<select name="" id="day_select_from" onchange="first_day_of_month()">
    <option value="">select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<select name="" id="weekday-from-year">
    <!-- <option value="sunday">sunday</option> -->
    <option value="monday">monday</option>
    <!-- <option value="tuesday">tuesday</option> -->
    <!-- <option value="wednesday">wednesday</option> -->
    <!-- <option value="thursday">thursday</option> -->
    <!-- <option value="friday">friday</option> -->
    <!-- <option value="saturday">saturday</option> -->
</select>
<div id="experiment_month">
    <?php
    for ($day = 1; $day <= 31; $day++) {
        echo "<div id='date_on_day_$day'>x</div>";
    }
    ?>
</div>



<script>
    var lastOpt = "";
    var date_selected = "";

    function first_day_of_month() {
        alert('hello');
        var date_selected = parseInt($('#day_select_from').val());
        if ((1 <= parseInt($('#day_select_from').val())) && (parseInt($('#day_select_from').val()) <= 7)) {
            // alert('hello1');
            $(function() {
                lastOpt = $('#day_select_from').find('option:last-child').attr('value');
            });
            for (var clearstart_day = 1; clearstart_day <= lastOpt; clearstart_day++) {
                $('#date_on_day_' + clearstart_day).html(" ");
            } //to clear 'x' from days

            var date_selected = parseInt($('#day_select_from').val());
            var du = parseInt(parseInt($('#day_select_from').val()) + 1) + 1;
            // alert('val :'+du);
            var fu = 0;
            var du = parseInt(parseInt($('#day_select_from').val()) + 1) + 1;

            if ($('#weekday-from-year').val() === 'monday') {
                $('#date_on_day_1').html("");
                $('#date_on_day_1').html(date_selected);
                for (var x = 2; x <= lastOpt; x++) {
                    for (du = 4; du <= 35; du++) {
                        $('#date_on_day_' + x).html(du)
                    }
                }
            }
            if ($('#weekday-from-year').val() === 'tuesday') {
                $('#date_on_day_2').html("");
                $('#date_on_day_2').html(date_selected);
                for (var x = 3; x <= lastOpt; x++) {
                    $('#date_on_day_' + x).html('r')
                };
            }
            if ($('#weekday-from-year').val() === 'wednesday') {
                $('#date_on_day_3').html("");
                $('#date_on_day_3').html(date_selected);
                for (var x = 4; x <= lastOpt; x++) {
                    $('#date_on_day_' + x).html('r')
                };
            }
            if ($('#weekday-from-year').val() === 'thursday') {
                $('#date_on_day_4').html("");
                $('#date_on_day_4').html(date_selected);
                for (var x = 5; x <= lastOpt; x++) {
                    $('#date_on_day_' + x).html('r')
                };
            }
            if ($('#weekday-from-year').val() === "friday") {
                $('#date_on_day_5').html("");
                $('#date_on_day_5').html(date_selected);
                for (var x = 6; x <= lastOpt; x++) {
                    $('#date_on_day_' + x).html('r')
                };
            }
            if ($('#weekday-from-year').val() == 'saturday') {
                $('#date_on_day_6').html("");
                $('#date_on_day_6').html(date_selected);
                for (var x = 7; x <= lastOpt; x++) {
                    $('#date_on_day_' + x).html('r')
                };
            }
            if ($('#weekday-from-year').val() == 'sunday') {
                $('#date_on_day_7').html("");
                $('#date_on_day_7').html(date_selected);
                for (var x = 8; x <= lastOpt; x++) {
                    $('#date_on_day_' + x).html('r')
                };
            }

        }
    }
</script>
```

The code is working on monday, January 3. I did it for one to answer easily. Query is tat 3 is selected as first day. Now I have to fill other days divs with next values like 4,5,6,7 if monday,3 is selected. The result I get is 31, means last day of month the nested loop gives last result. I am sure nested loop is not stepping right.

It puts 35 in all other divs. [It is showing first value but all other are shown 35](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8GSs.png)

Comment: You could use else-ifs instead of multiple ifs to make it more performant or you could use numbers in #weekday-from-year select to make it more dynamic and omit the ifs entirely.

Comment: It would help if you could narrow down your code to *just* the part that's causing a problem.  See [mcve].

Comment: It *looks like* your issue is with "==monday" and `for x`..`for du` - the reason they all have the same value is that you have `$('#date_on_day_' + x).html(du)` - so `du` might as well be `du=35`.   It *looks like* you don't need the outer for-x with just ` $('#date_on_day_' + du).html(du)`  or it should be ` $('#date_on_day_' + (du - 2)).html(du)`

Comment: `$('#date_on_day_x').html("");` and `$('#date_on_day_x').html(date_selected);` are redundant. You can omit the first one.

Comment: actually while we first loa the page, x is displayed on all divs. it has to be cleared before  using $('#date_on_day_x').html(""); then putting  $('#date_on_day_x').html(date_selected);. because if we select february first it gives only 28 divs data and rest live "x" then we select march the old data does not go away . do what i said opposite. so clearing all was necessary. . the issue is that i get 35 on all divs  after first date. not the next dates. i divided in 7 columns because there are 7 days starting from monday to sunday. first line contains first date.  please answer the loop issue

Comment: @shedrich i used elseif but it mostly stops at first if and not comes to second means elseif may be i am facing issues cause i was First Access then MS visual Studio andd now PHP javascript developer. but in Javascript and PHP i noted mostly If works instead on elseif. that is why I had already tried that . here issue is that all works fne not the next days . only first day is displayed. I shall soon solve it but till then i had asked community as that had  helped me a lot in learning.

Comment: if ($('#weekday-from-year').val() === 'monday') {
                $('#date_on_day_1').html("");
                $('#date_on_day_1').html(date_selected);
                for (var x = 2; x <= lastOpt; x++) {
                    for (du = 4; du <= 35; du++) {
                        $('#date_on_day_' + x).html(du)
                    }
                }
            } part is causing issue

Comment: if($('#weekday-from-year').val()==='monday'){if(($('#day_select_from').val())==1){var difference=0}else if(($('#day_select_from').val())==2){difference=1;}else if(($('#day_select_from').val())==3){difference=2;}else if(($('#day_select_from').val())==4){difference=3;}else if(($('#day_select_from').val())==5){difference=4;}else if(($('#day_select_from').val())==6){difference=5;}else if(($('#day_select_from').val())==7){difference=6;}$('#date_on_day_1').html("");$('#date_on_day_1').html(date_selected);for(fu=du;fu <= lastOpt; fu++){$('#date_on_day_'+(fu-difference)).html(fu)}} That code solved